# how to sort joined tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

help please write orm-request.

tables:

```
users:
id: integer
name: varchar

posts:
id: integer
title: varchar
user_id: integer
views: integer
```

models:

```
User:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :posts,  dependent:  :destroy
end

Posts:
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :user
end
```

controller:

```
def popular_diary
  @users = User.joins(:posts).group_by(:user_id).order('SUM(posts.views)')
end
```

html:

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <div class="row">
      <%= link_to user_posts_url(user.id) do %>
        <div><%= user.name %></div>
      <% end %>  
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I need that all users hatched in a certain order. `order ('SUM (posts.views)`

The problem is that the screen displays the following error message:

> wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: What's the whole error message? It is most likely totally unrelated. Also you might want to learn how to read a stack trace. http://railscasts.com/episodes/24-the-stack-trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `group`, not `group_by`

```
def popular_diary
  @users = User.joins(:posts).group(:user_id).order('SUM(posts.views)')
end
```